# Шарик следящий за курсором мыши лагает

Tags: javascript, html, css, прокрутка, scrollmagic

У меня есть шарик, который следит за курсором мыши, но проблема состоит в том, что он лагает, когда я скролю. Как избавиться от этого? Я еще использую ScrollMagic вот этот пример на всю страницу, может из-за [этого](http://www.creative-seo.ru/blog/plagin-scrollmagic-polnoekrannoe-slideshow/).
И можно ли сделать следящий шарик более мягким, то есть как-то можно получить clientX и clientY с десятыми например.

Upd: у меня еще подключен плагин SmoothScroll, скорее всего это происходит из-за него, но вот как исправить проблему, потому что нужен и мягкий скролл и шарик

```js
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    X = event.clientX;
    Y = event.clientY;
});

function move() {
    document.getElementById('circle').style.left = X + 'px';
    document.getElementById('circle').style.top = Y + 'px';
    setTimeout(move, 10);
}

move();
```

```css
.circle-cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: -15px 0 0 -15px;
  position: fixed;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.15s, left 0.15s;
  transition: top 0.15s, left 0.15s;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="circle" class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Вы уже один раз нашли элемент, сохраните ссылку в переменной

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame  - слишком часто опрашиваете положение, можно подписаться на анимацию

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Посмотрел на ответ `h` и остановил анимацию
Работает и на touch устройствах

```js
const circle = document.querySelector('#circle');
const mouse = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
};
let y = 0;
let x = 0;

function moveFunc(event) {
  const clientX = event.changedTouches ? event.changedTouches[0].clientX : event.clientX;
  const clientY = event.changedTouches ? event.changedTouches[0].clientY : event.clientY;
  mouse.x = clientX - circle.offsetWidth / 2;
  mouse.y = clientY - circle.offsetHeight / 2;
  parallax();
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', moveFunc);
window.addEventListener('touchmove', moveFunc);

function parallax() {
  const speed = 100; // чем меньше, тем быстрее
  const nextX = (mouse.x - x) / speed;
  const nextY = (mouse.y - y) / speed;
  if (Math.abs(nextX) > 0.05 || Math.abs(nextY) > 0.05) {
    requestAnimationFrame(parallax);
  }
  // console.log(1); // Раскомментируй для проверки, что цикл не бесконечный

  x += nextX;
  y += nextY;

  circle.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`;
}

parallax();
```

```css
html {
  cursor: none;
}

.circle-cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="circle" class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 7):

Лагает, потому что у элемента есть `transition: top 0.15s, left 0.15s;` и на каждое изменение координат: `document.getElementById('circle').style.left = X + 'px';` он срабатывает + объект перемещается посредством `top` `left`, что тоже влияет. Для любого движения в css нужно использовать `transform`. Ну, и, 10мс - большое значение для плавной анимации, лучше использовать `requestAnimationFrame`, браузер сам подберет время перерисовки.

```js
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;
var mouse = { x: 0,y: 0 };

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
                            // смещение в центр
  mouse.x = event.clientX - circle.offsetWidth / 2;
  mouse.y = event.clientY - circle.offsetHeight / 2;
});

function move() {
  X += (mouse.x - X) * 0.1;
  Y += (mouse.y - Y) * 0.1;
  circle.style.transform = `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, ${X}, ${Y})`;
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}

move();
```

```css
.circle-cursor {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="circle" class="circle-cursor circle-cursor--inner"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Почему на stackoverflow любят писать бесконечные анимации и их не останавливают

Comment: Извини пожалуйста (

Comment: @МихаилКамахин в чем проблема бесконечной анимации? Анимация с использованием `requestAnimationFrame` экономит ресурсы, в отличии от `setInterval`/`setTimeout`. Не вижу проблем для беспокойств. В данной задаче, кастомный курсор будет использоваться постоянно, поэтому делать дополнительные проверки нет смысла, если человек переключится на другую вкладку, анимация сама остановится.

Comment: @MoloF она же всё время вызывается

Comment: @MoloF ну так-то да, но как-то сердечку больно из-а этого

Comment: @МихаилКамахин валидольчику попейте ..если сердечко пошаливает :))

Comment: @MoloF а нет!!! Код в цикле будет выполняться, когда курсор стоит на месте, лишний раз нагружая браузер. Останавливать анимацию всё-таки лучше. Т.е. человек пошёл пить чай. Забыл про открытый комп, на день (не идёт в сон комп, как у меня, например). А там браузер гоняет эти оптимизированные циклы

Comment: @ᅠhᅠПривет! Решил всё с чистого листа начать? Жаль было, когда ты учетку удалил. Рад, что ты вернулся