# Плавное анимирование x, y

Tags: javascript, анимация

Я хочу написать анимацию плавного движения элемента от прошлого положения, до текущего (Так работает плавный курсор).

Но вообще не понимаю как это делать, опираясь на время.

Пример с анимацией, не опираясь на время: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1206110/331312

Я сначала думал, что есть x1 y1, x2 y2 две точки. Надо плавно анимировать точку по пути от одной точки до другой. Но это не так. Не понимаю что делать. Подскажите

```js
const rectangleNode = document.querySelector('.rectangle');

window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  move(e.x, e.y, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

function move(eventX, eventY, windowWidth, windowHeight) {
  const x = (eventX / windowWidth) * 2 - 1;
  const y = (eventY / windowHeight) * 2 - 1;

  const computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle(rectangleNode)
  const lastX = Number(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('--x'));
  const lastY = Number(computedStyle.getPropertyValue('--y'));

  animate(1000, (time, animationTime, progress) => {

    const interX = x + (lastX - x) * progress;
    const interY = y + (lastY - y) * progress;

    rectangleNode.style.setProperty('--x', interX);
    rectangleNode.style.setProperty('--y', interY);

    return true;
  });
}

function animate(seconds, func) {
  let startTime = null;

  animate.quantity = animate.quantity === undefined ? 0 : animate.quantity + 1;
  const animateQuantity = animate.quantity; // Запоминаем номер анимации

  function loopAnimation(timeStamp) {

    if (animate.quantity !== animateQuantity) { // Если номер текущей анимации и последней анимации не совпадает, то остановить анимацию
      return false;
    }

    startTime = startTime === null ? timeStamp : startTime;
    const time = timeStamp - startTime;

    const progress = (time / seconds) > 1 ? 1 : (time / seconds);
    const resFunc = func(time, seconds, progress);

    if (time < seconds && resFunc) {
      requestAnimationFrame(loopAnimation);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loopAnimation);
}
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --transitionTimingFunction: ease;
  --transitionDuration: 0.05s;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  --r: 0;
  --g: 26;
  --b: 52;
  background-color: rgb(var(--r), var(--g), var(--b));
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rectangle {
  --x: 1;
  --y: 1;
  --maxTranslateX: 20px;
  --maxTranslateY: 20px;
  --background: linear-gradient(to right top, green, #71da71);
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  --skewDeg: calc(-18deg * var(--x) * var(--y));
  transform: skew(0, var(--skewDeg));
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

.rectangle__body {
  padding: 35px 25px;
  background: var(--background);
  max-width: 180px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle__body-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.3;
  --maxTranslateX: 50px;
  --maxTranslateY: 50px;
  --translateX: calc( (var(--maxTranslateX) * var(--x) + 0px) * -1);
  --translateY: calc( (var(--maxTranslateY) * var(--y) + 0px) * -1);
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
}

.rectangle__body-pos-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.rectangle__body-text {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

.rectangle__body-text-span {
  display: block;
  --translateX: calc( var(--maxTranslateX) * var(--x));
  --translateY: calc( var(--maxTranslateY) * var(--y));
  transform: translate3d( var(--translateX), var(--translateY), 0);
}

.rectangle__body-text-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  filter: blur(7px);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle">

  <div class="rectangle__body-shadow">
  </div>

  <div class="rectangle__body">
    <div class="rectangle__body-pos-relative">

      <div class="rectangle__body-text">
        <span class="rectangle__body-text-span">Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений</span>
      </div>

      <div class="rectangle__body-text-shadow">
        Подразделения и сотрудников научных учреждений
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: я не понял что надо получить

Comment: @StrangerintheQ чтобы работало как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1206110/331312 только, чтобы можно было указывать время анимации

Comment: @StrangerintheQ что-то мне кажется, что это глупая идея анимировать за какое-то время. Потому что если две точки находятся слишком близко, то анимация также будет идти такое же время, что будет выглядеть не очень

Comment: Настройте скорость перемещения указателя мыши в Windows и готово. А так совершенно не читается никакое замедление или что там по ссылке. Кружочек есть, не более. Я точно не могу уловить ничего.

Comment: @Leonid всмысле. Он плавно ездит за мышкой. А не резко, как обычный курсор ходит

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1206079/342397 - в этом ответе заметно.

Comment: нормальный плани- каждый кадр сдвигать курсор на 10 % от оставшегося пути